# how to write a ruby script running on different system

Tags: ruby, shell

I have a ruby script, which declare the ruby path in the first line

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
```

But, I need it to be run in different system. And the path of Ruby are different in different system. How to handle this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In unix systems you can get away with

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
```

This has the effect of using the `ruby` found on the path.  `env` is a core binary on pretty much every unix.

Comment: Not only on Linux: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html

Comment: Thanks, so this should be a standard practice for shell script, right?